# Issues with certs when setting up Hyperledger dev environment

Tags: installation, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have downloaded Hyperledger v1 code base from gerrit.  I am on windows 8.1 which does not natively support docker, I am using vagrant to bootstrap the environment.

When I do vagrant up. I get errors while downloading docker-compose, Go etc.

This I fixed with the less than optimal solution of using insecure download(curl -k).
curl -k -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Which I don't like, but atleast it allows me to proceed. However, now the build fails in the make file when it tries to 
git clone https://github.com/golang/lint

here is the error i get-

```
==> default: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/golang/lint/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
==> default: package github.com/golang/lint/golint: exit status 128
==> default: Makefile:47: recipe for target 'gotool.golint' failed
```

I understand it is because I do not have the right certificates in my ubuntu install, but how do I get them and install them here. I am a noob.

I want to complete my installation and preferably do the setup.sh steps without -k in curl.

Extra Info:
I have added   config.vm.box_download_insecure = true in my vagrant file. It was not downloading without it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have got no answers and I was able to resolve the problem. I will post a solution for posterity.
As you know, I was not able to curl to github.  I was not able to get 'go get' working with a GitHub URL. It all failed with the same error.

However, I naively searched the internet for a solution. I even generated ssh keys and uploaded them to github. I was able to verify that GitHub knows my identity because of the ssh keys, but I was still not able to download open source code.

The whole issue was that my ubuntu xenial machine did not trust github.com. Which in effect means that the Root Certificate of github was not in my root certificate list.

After meandering through ssh land, I decided to get the certificate fixed. 
My first solution was to redownload all the certificates. Github is popular, it should have its CA in the pre bundled CA list was my reasoning. - Did not work.

Second - download the certificate from github.com and add it to my machine.  I forgot the very basic that it is not a ROOT CA so - Did not work.

Finally,  I downloaded the ROOT CA, certificate added it to my ubuntu's list of certificates and voila.

**Steps:**

1. Download Github ROOT CA(Certifying Authority) certificate using your browser.  I used Chrome.
   Settings> Show Advanced Settings> manage certertificates> trusted root certification authorities>caadmin
2. Let's name it github.cer{base-64 encoded}, and place it in your /vagrant folder (Folder shared between your host and your vm)
3. cp github.com /etc/ssl/certs/
4. Run c_rehash
5. Run sudo update-ca-certificates

Once done. log out of Ubuntu (Ctrl+D), halt vagrant and bring vagrant up again with provisioning and Voila....